# Async Await and ContinueWith not working as expected

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, continuewith

I have [the following code](https://github.com/FoundatioFx/Foundatio/blob/29ea509cc5f0067e081d2cbd672ff1fdae21ac62/src/Foundatio/Jobs/IJob.cs#L16-L26) that runs on .NET Standard 2.0:

```
public static Task<JobResult> TryRunAsync(this IJob job,
                                          CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    return job.RunAsync(cancellationToken)
        .ContinueWith(t => {
             if (t.IsFaulted)
                 return JobResult.FromException(t.Exception.InnerException);
             if (t.IsCanceled)
                 return JobResult.Cancelled;

             return t.Result;
         });
}
```

And we noticed it wasn't running as expected. We thought that when you awaited the call to TryRun it would always call the continuation which could handle the exception/cancellation and return a job result. We were hoping to reduce the amount of async state machines created... However, this is not the case it just blows up. Here is a smaller sample (create a new .net core 2.0 console app and paste the following:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main()
        {
            // works
            await DoStuff();
            Console.ReadKey();

            // blows up
            await TryRun();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static Task DoStuff()
        {
            return Method()
                .ContinueWith(t => Throws())
                .ContinueWith(t => {
                    if (t.IsFaulted)
                        Console.WriteLine("Faulted");
                    else if (t.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
                        Console.WriteLine("Success");
                });
        }

        public static Task Method()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Method");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public static Task TryRun()
        {
            return Throws()
                .ContinueWith(t => {
                    if (t.IsFaulted)
                        Console.WriteLine("Faulted");
                    else if (t.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
                        Console.WriteLine("Success");
                });
        }

        public static Task Throws()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Throws");
            throw new ApplicationException("Grr");
        }
    }
}
```

You may need `<LangVersion>Latest</LangVersion>` In your csproj.

**UPDATE**

We ended up going with the following code:

```
public static Task<JobResult> TryRunAsync(this IJob job, 
                                           CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<JobResult>(null);
    try {
        var task = job.RunAsync(cancellationToken);
        task.ContinueWith((task2, state2) => {
            var tcs2 = (TaskCompletionSource<object>)state2;
            if (task2.IsCanceled) {
                tcs2.SetResult(JobResult.Cancelled);
            } else if (task2.IsFaulted) {
                tcs2.SetResult(JobResult.FromException(task2.Exception));
            } else {
                tcs2.SetResult(JobResult.Success);
            }
        }, tcs, cancellationToken);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        tcs.SetResult(JobResult.FromException(ex));
    }

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method throws is actually throwing an exception when called, not returning a faulted `Task`.  There is no `Task` for you to add a continuation to; it's simply going up the call stack before even reaching the `ContinueWith` call.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161464/discussion-on-answer-by-servy-async-await-and-continuewith-not-working-as-expect).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there is no task created here. For instance if you did a loop you would stay on the same thread and same stack. You could see the correct behaviour by doing a Task.FromException in the Throws method rather than throwing. Also in core 2.1 at least you might find that an async method will be just as fast or even faster than the continuation version and less allocaty. Worth checking your trace numbers before trying to optimise away the state machine. Also if you are throwing exceptions your state machine is definitely the least of your perf concerns.